# Error while installing spree

Tags: ruby, installation, spree

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.2.8) ruby depends on
      railties (= 3.2.8) ruby

    sass-rails (~> 4.0.0) ruby depends on
      railties (4.0.0)
```

This error occured, how can i fix this error.
I do not know railties and sass-rails version.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Rails 3.2 you should use all gems with that branch too, i.e.:

```
Gemfile:

gem https://github.com/rails/sass-rails.git, branch: '3-2-stable'
```

You can see branches listed on GH next to green compare button (with new layout).

What if specific gem doesn't have branches? Well, you can fork it, modify the gemspec,see what fails and fix it.